# tips on using a variable length in awk printf

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am a beginner in awk. If I have an input of

```
id varchar(2),
name varchar(10),
address varchar(20)
```

Can I use awk to make it look like

```
id         varchar(2),
name       varchar(10),
address    varchar(20)

awk -F"|" ' {printf "%s%10d\n" ,$2, $3 }'
```

I want to be able to mention a variable instead of `10` in the format specifier and make it configurable

```
awk -F"|" ' {length=10printf "%s%lengthd\n" ,$2, $3 }'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just use `column -t file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In awk the `printf` format string is just a regular string which can be concatenated.

So if you want to adjust the length of the parameter, use it like this:

`awk -F"|" '{length=10; printf "%s%" length "d\n" ,$2, $3 }'`